# How to run NUnit tests from inside Visual Studio?

Tags: nunit

I have downloaded the source for NHiberate 4.0.4 and want to run some of the unit tests. Not sure how to go about doing this. I played around with NUnit several years ago and seem to remember there was a addin for visual studio but couldn't find it. Is there a way to run the NUnit tests from within Visual Studio, similar to the way JUnit works in eclipse?

Comment: Install the "NUnit VS adapter" VS extension. There are separate versions depending if you are using NUnit 2.X or NUnit 3.X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an old question but still deserves a step-by-step, how-to answer with reference to the latest versions of VS (2019) and NUnit (4.0) since NUnit tests won't run in VS 2019 out-of-the-box.

Here's how to set it up:

1. Install the **NUnit 3 Test Adapter** extension to VS by selecting *Extensions > Manage Extensions* from the main menu. Restart VS to complete the installation.
2. Add a Class Library project to your solution. Right click on the project and select *Manage NuGet Packages* menu option. Browse for **NUnit** and install it.
3. Add a public, non-static class to the project to host your tests. Mark the class with the `[TestFixture]` attribute. Also, don't forget to add the required `using NUnit.Framework` directive.
4. Add a public method to the class and mark it with the `[Test]` attribute. Repeat with as many methods as necessary.
5. Build the project and then select *Test > Run All Tests* from VS main menu. The Test Explorer will pop up and show you the progress and outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2012 or higher, then yes, you can run NUnit tests directly from Visual Studio. I think [NUnit Test Adapter](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=2.6.4)

may be what you need. For VS 2013 and higher this may not be necessary - if NUnit Framework is installed and the project references it, anything declared as [TestFixture]/[Test] has a Click to Run icon on the left.

Hope this helps!